# Using map from purrr to extract a value conditional on another variable

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to map values from multiple dataframes to a primary dataframe.

The example below works partially and i am having trouble in the last part

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(data.table)

# main data
eid <- c(111,333,555,777,999)
value <-c(121,135,565,400,450)
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(eid,value),stringsAsFactors=F)

# data from mi to be mapped to main data
eid <- c(111,222,444)
date <- c(134,234,213)
mi <- as.data.frame(cbind(eid,mi.value),stringsAsFactors=F)

# data from cva to be mapped to main data
eid <- c(333,444,555,666)
date <- c(124,132,125,457)
cva <-as.data.frame(cbind(eid,cva.value),stringsAsFactors=F)

# using map to see if eid in 'mi' and 'cva' appear in main data


each.subsequent <- map(list(mi,cva),~
                     as.integer(dat$eid %in% .x$eid))
names(each.subsequent) <- c("mi","cva")
each.subsequent <- as.data.frame(each.subsequent)
```

This next bit does not work

```
# maps the numerical value next to the eid
each.subsequent.value <- map(list(mi,cva),~
    ifelse (dat$eid == .x$eid, .x$date,NA))
```

I have found a work around using right joins but this requires lot of code writing. So i had two questions:

1) Is there a 'map' way of extarcting the $date values from each of the mi and cva dataframes matching the eid?

2) What is the purpose of the '~' and .x in the code above that works?

The desired output should be

```
structure(list(eid = c(111, 333, 555, 777, 999), value = c(121, 
135, 565, 400, 450), mi = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), cva = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), mi.date = c(134, NA, NA, NA, NA), cva.date = c(NA, 
124, 125, NA, NA)), .Names = c("eid", "value", "mi", "cva", "mi.date", 
"cva.date"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `as.data.frame(cbind(` can get you into trouble `cbind` converts to `matrix` and matrix can have only a single `class`.  Better is `data.frame(`

Comment: thanks akrun - as always very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with two `left_join`, unsless I'm missing something (a lot more `data.frames` maybe):

```
dat %>% 
  left_join(mi, by ="eid") %>% 
  left_join(cva, by ="eid")
#   eid value mi.value cva.value
# 1 111   121      134        NA
# 2 333   135       NA       124
# 3 555   565       NA       125
# 4 777   400       NA        NA
# 5 999   450       NA        NA
```

Edit:

if you have more `data.frames` use `reduce`:

```
list(dat, mi, cva) %>% reduce(left_join, by = "eid")
```

Comment: Thanks - yeah  that kind of what i ended up doing. I have a lot of those small linking data frames i.e. mi, cva etc. With the above method will need to type all that code up so was hoping for a way to loop with purr::map

Comment: See my update, with `reduce` you need to type only once